# Proof of L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I recently tried to prove L'Hospitals Rule on my own but I'm not sure if it is correct because it differs from all other proofs that I have already found.

Here's the proof:

Let functions $f,g:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $(a,b)$ except possibly at $x_{0}$ $\epsilon$ $(a,b)$.If:

1. $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} g(x)=0$
2. ($\forall x $ $\epsilon$ $ (a,b)\setminus$ {$x_{0}$}) $\exists f′(x)$  and $\exists g′(x)$ which is diferent from zero
3. $\exists lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f′(x)}{g′(x)}=A$ where $A$ $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\cup$ {$-\infty,+\infty$}

Then there exists $lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=A$

Proof:

1. Let $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})=0$ , and $f′, g′$ be continuous on $(a,b)$ , then :

$lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f′(x)}{g′(x)}=\frac{f′(x_{0})}{g′(x_{0})}=\frac{lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}}{lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{g(x)-g(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}}=lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{g(x)-g(x_{0})}=lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

1. General proof (regardless of the values $f(x_{0})$,$g(x_{0})$)

Let's consider the functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ such that :

$F(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) &\text{if x is different from  } x_{0} \\{}\\ 0 &\text{ for } x=x_{0} .\end{cases}$

$G(x)=\begin{cases} g(x) &\text{if x is different from  } x_{0} \\{}\\ 0 &\text{ for } x=x_{0} .\end{cases}$

It is obvious that $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are continuous at $x_{0}$ $\epsilon$ $(a,b)$.

Let $x>x_{0}$ , this means that $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are continuous on $[x_{0},x]$, differentiable at least on $(x_{0},x)$ and $\forall$ $x_{1}$ $\epsilon$ $(x_{0},x)$ $\exists$ $F′(x)$  and $\exists G′(x)$ which is different from zero. So this means that functions $F(x),G(x)$ satisfy the conditions of Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem therefore there $\exists$ $c$ $\epsilon$ $(x_{0},x)$ such that:

$\frac{f′(c)}{g′(c)}=\frac{F′(c)}{G′(c)}=\frac{F(x)-F(x_{0})}{G(x)-G(x_{0})}=\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

(Because $c$ and $x$ are different from $x_{0}$)

Now from $c$ $\epsilon$ $ (x_{0},x)$ when $x \rightarrow x_{0}^+$ $\implies$ $c\to x_{0}^+$

Thus we have:

$lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}^+}\frac{f′(x)}{g′(x)}=lim_{c \rightarrow x_{0}^+} \frac{f′(c)}{g′(c)}=lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

Analogously we prove when $x\to x_{0}^-$

When $x\to \infty$ we define function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous on $(a,\infty)$ and substitute $x=\frac{1}{t}$, so we'll have:

$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{f(\frac{1}{t})}{g(\frac{1}{t})}=lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\big(f(\frac{1}{t})\big)′}{\big(g(\frac{1}{t})\big)′}=lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\frac{-1}{t^2} f′(\frac{1}{t})}{\frac{-1}{t^2}g′(\frac{1}{t})}=lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f′(\frac{1}{t})}{g′(\frac{1}{t})}=lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f′(x)}{g′(x)}=A$

When $x \to -\infty$ then we take $t \to 0^-$

If someone would tell me if my proof is correct or not I'd really appreciate it.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct.  Early in the proof you assert that if you let $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=0$ then $f$ and $g$ (you claim $f'$ and $g'$ which is also false, but I think you meant $f$ and $g$) are continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)$.  But this isn't the case.  They weren't necessarily continuous at $x_0$ to start with.  Substituting $0$ for their value there won't make them continuous much less differentiable.

Comment: Can you explain it to me clearly what's wrong cause I don't understand?  Based on the conditions given above for $f(x_{0})=g(x_{o})=0$ functions $f,g$ are continuous and their first derivative exist everywhere on $(a,b)$ therefore the above statement holds. And what about the second part of the proof is it correct?

Comment: Why read the second part when the first part is wrong?  As for the first part, possibly you meant "Let $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})=0$ , and let the functions $f′, g′$ are continuous on $(a,b)$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then " but what you wrote was "Let $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})=0$ , so functions $f′, g′$ are continuous on $(a,b)$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then :", which contains a conclusion that doesn't follow from its premise.  Why would I keep reading after that?

Comment: Cause the second part is a general proof so the first part is included on the second one that's why you should keep reading! Okay I'll change the first part.

Comment: is it now correct?